# Can't create a variable with just one letter

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I wish the variables could be declared with only one letter in the name.
When I write Integer aa; all work, but
when I type Integer a; then grun says: mismatched input 'a' expecting ID.
I've seen the inverse problem but it didn't help. I think my code is right but I can't see where I'm wrong. This is my lexer:

```
lexer grammar Symbols;

...

LineComment: '//' ~[\u000A\u000D]* -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
DelimetedComment: '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

String: '"' .*? '"' ;
Character: '\'' (EscapeSeq | .) '\'' ;
IntegerLiteral: '0' | (ADD?| SUB) DecDigitNoZero DecDigit+ ;
FloatLiteral: ((ADD? | SUB) (DecDigitNoZero DecDigit*)? DOT DecDigit+ | IntegerLiteral) [F] ;
DoubleLiteral: ((ADD? | SUB) (DecDigitNoZero DecDigit*)? DOT DecDigit+ | IntegerLiteral) [D]  ;
LongLiteral: IntegerLiteral [L] ;
HexLiteral: '0' [xX] HexDigit (HexDigit | UNDERSCORE)* ;
BinLiteral: '0' [bB] BinDigit (BinDigit | UNDERSCORE)* ;
OctLiteral: '0' [cC] OctDigit (OctDigit | UNDERSCORE)* ;
Booleans: TRUE | FALSE ;
Number: IntegerLiteral | FloatLiteral | DoubleLiteral | BinLiteral | HexLiteral | OctLiteral | LongLiteral ;
EscapeSeq: UniCharacterLiteral | EscapedIdentifier;
UniCharacterLiteral: '\\' 'u' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit ;
EscapedIdentifier: '\\' ('t' | 'b' | 'r' | 'n' | '\'' | '"' | '\\' | '$') ;
HexDigit: [0-9a-fA-F] ;
BinDigit: [01] ;
OctDigit: [0-7];
DecDigit: [0-9];
DecDigitNoZero: [1-9];

ID: [a-z] ([a-zA-Z_] | [0-9])*;
TYPE: [A-Z] ([a-zA-Z] | UNDERSCORE | [0-9])* ;

DATATYPE: Number | String | Character | Booleans ;
```

Comment: That cannot be reproduced with the grammar you posted. Please post your entire grammar.

Comment: @BartKiers Done

Comment: thanks, it was what I suspected: a rule defined befire your `ID` rule got matched, as already explained by sepp2k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an error like "Unexpected input 'foo', expected BAR" and you think "But 'foo' *is* a BAR", the first thing you should do is to print the token stream for your input (you can do this by running `grun Symbols tokens -tokens inputfile`). If you do this, you'll see that the `a` in your input is recognized as a `HexDigit`, not as an `ID`.

Why does this happen? Because both `HexDigit` and `ID` match the input `a` and ANTLR (like most lexer generators) resolves ambiguities according to the maximal munch rule: When multiple rules can match the current input, it chooses the one that produces the longest match (which is why variables with more than one letter work) and then resolves ties by picking the one that is defined first, which is `HexDigit` in this case.

Note that the lexer does not care which lexer rules are used by the parser and when. The lexer decides which tokens to produce solely based on the contents of the lexer grammar, so the lexer does not know or care that the parser wants an `ID` right now. It looks at all rules that match and then picks one according to the maximal munch rule and that's it.

In your case you never actually use `HexDigit` in your parser grammar, so there is no reason why you'd ever want a `HexDigit` token to be created. Therefore `HexDigit` should not be a lexer rule - it should be a `fragment`:

```
fragment HexDigit : [0-9a-fA-F];
```

This also applies to your other rules that aren't used in the parser, including all the `...Digit` rules.

PS: Your `Number` rule will never match because of these same rules. It should probably be a parser rule instead (or the other number rules should be fragments if you don't care which kind of number literal you have).

Comment: Excellent answer, as usual. I took the liberty to make a small edit.